# How do i get my protein model in my webpage?

Tags: html

How do I make a 3D protein model using this pdb file and an export this 3D model on my webpage. I do not want to use Jmol. 
Is there another program or any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try something like this http://webglmol.sourceforge.jp/index-en.html